# How to make list item value not reference to the object

Tags: c#, list, object, generics, xmldatasource

my list item that is already added update base on current object (obj) value.
how to make list not update or how to copy obj?

```
    public static void ReadData<T>(string filename, T obj,string node)
    {
        var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.Load(filename);
        List<T> objectList = new List<T>();
        XmlNodeList xmlNodeList = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("//"+node);

        for (var i = 0; i < xmlNodeList?.Count; i++)
        {
            var j = 0;
            foreach (var objectProperty in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if (objectProperty.CanRead)
                {
                    object value;
                    if (objectProperty.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
                    {
                        value = bool.Parse(xmlNodeList[i].ChildNodes[j].InnerText);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       value= xmlNodeList[i].ChildNodes[j].InnerText;
                    }
                    objectProperty.SetValue(obj, value);
                    j++;
                }
            }
            objectList.Add(obj);
        }
```

}

Comment: If `T` is a `struct`, then it is already a copy. If `T` is a `class`, then : the only way to do this is via a shallow or deep clone. At that point, you should be searching for "how to clone an object in .NET"

Comment: "how to clone non specific object?" - two people have already given you two different approaches to that; have you tried either? how did it go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.You can implement IConeable

```
public class ClonableClass : ICloneable
{
   public object Clone()
   {
      return this.MemberwiseClone();
   }
}
```

Now a and b do not refer to the same object.

```
var a = new ClonableClass ();
var b = (ClonableClass)a.Clone();
```

2.The simplest way to deep clone is to just serialize the object then deserialize it.

```
var objStr= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
var newObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(objStr);
```

3.Another way will require brute force coding but you can get every last bit of performance gain. You can just create a new object then assign all properties manually.

Comment: note that this will work, but implements a shallow clone; it is often important to know whether a clone is shallow or deep. I would also probably recommend fixing the typing, i.e. `public Foo Clone() { /* actual code */ } object ICloneable.Clone() => Clone();`

Comment: For the easy, you can just serialize the object the deserialize it.

Answer (score 1):

Serialization and deserialization an object is an option to clone objects.

```
public static T Clone<T>(this T source)
{
    var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(source);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(serialized);
}
```

Then clone the desired object;

```
var obj = new SampleClass
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = ""
};
var clonedObj = obj.Clone();
```